# Detect if standard library containers are included

Tags: c++, stl

I'm looking for a cross platform way at compile time,  to determine whether or not the Standard library containers are included (vector, map, set, list)
e.g. 
    #ifdef HAS_VECTOR
        // do something with std vector here
    #endif

Comment: Included as in supported by the toolchain or included as in somewhere in the project someone is using a std container?

Comment: Sorry, but I have to ask: Why?

Comment: `#include <vector>` followed by `#if 1` should do the trick

Comment: Hi MM - clever! If you post this as an answer I'll accept!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the headers are available to be included:

If you're using what the standard calls a *freestanding implementation* (limited library support) then you can check that with the macro `__STDC_HOSTED__`. If `__STDC_HOSTED__` is defined to `1` then any standard-conforming compiler will provide a proper standard library. A conforming hosted implementation cannot pick and choose which container headers to provide so there are not individual macros for each container. Clang provides the non-standard [`__has_include`](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html) feature to test for a header file in a `#if` but this is not portable.

If you want to know if the headers have already been included in this translation unit:

You cannot detect this unless you manually defined your own macro every time you include the given header. Nothing bad will happen if you include a standard library header multiple times.

Answer (score -1):

Seriously, just include what you need.  If they've already been included, then it's not a problem.